# Validating a Combo-Box Selection

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a combo box in the XAML written as

```
<ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Options}" 
           SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CurrentValue}"/>
```

And the "`CurrentValue`" is implemented in the ViewModel class as

```
private string m_CurrentValue;
public string CurrentValue
{
    get { return this.m_CurrentValue; }
    set
    {
        if (m_CurrentValue != value)
        {
            if (IsValid(value))
            {
                this.m_CurrentValue = value;
                SetData(this.m_CurrentValue);
            }

            this.SendPropertyChangedEvent(nameof(this.CurrentValue));
        }
    }
}
```

Here before setting `CurrentValue`, it is validated for some condition. My intention is to change ComboBox box selection to the previous value if the validation fails. This is not working for combo-boxes, however this method works perfectly for CheckBox controls - code snippet given below.

```
<CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding Path=CurrentValue}" Width="15" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsEnabled}"/>

private bool m_CurrentValue;
public bool CurrentValue
{
    get { return this.m_CurrentValue; }
    set
    {
        if (m_CurrentValue != value)
        {
            if (IsValid(value))
            {
                this.m_CurrentValue = value;
                SetData(this.m_CurrentValue);
            }

            this.SendPropertyChangedEvent(nameof(this.CurrentValue));
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to make this work for ComboBox? Any alternate implementation is also fine.

Comment: What happens if you make the selecteditem binding twoway?

Comment: @Andy same behavior

Comment: @FaisalM I think the better approach would be using a `ValidationRule` on your `Binding` or fill your `ComboBox` only with valid items. Because i think from user perspective its always bad if an entered value changes without any feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to make this work for `ComboBox`? Any alternate implementation is also fine.

You could set the backing field to the previous value using the dispatcher as suggested [here](https://nathan.alner.net/2010/04/25/cancelling-selection-change-in-a-bound-wpf-combo-box/):

```
private string m_CurrentValue;
public string CurrentValue
{
    get { return this.m_CurrentValue; }
    set
    {
        if (m_CurrentValue != value)
        {
            string previousValue = m_CurrentValue;
            //set the field
            this.m_CurrentValue = value;
            if (IsValid(value))
            {
                SetData(this.m_CurrentValue);
                this.SendPropertyChangedEvent(nameof(this.CurrentValue));
            }
            else
            {
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    m_CurrentValue = previousValue;
                    this.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(this.CurrentValue));
                }), DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please refer to the link for more information.

Comment: My bad. Don't know what made me say that!

Comment: @mm8 Thanks. This worked. Is it possible to use the same logic for TextBox? When I tried it is not working.

Comment: @FaisalM: I haven't tried. Please ask a new question if you have a new issue.

Answer (score 0):

Create a user control with a combobox within it which will handle your needs. Have dependency properties which you can track and if need be change due state values you have setup to process the operations within the contained combobox.

Create an internal state variable which has the index of the current combo selection. When an operation detects a return that previous state, set the internal combobox to that value.